# Best login management solution without database in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, password-protection, login-control

I am seeking a simple and best solution to manage user logins (username & password) in a private network (localhost) web page without setting up MySQL or any such database systems? I am running Apache with PHP. It will be helpful if anybody give a PHP demo.

Comment: Do you have an LDAP or Windows Active Directory server that you could utilize usernames and passwords from, on this local network?

Comment: I am having a windows vista system running apache...

Comment: User management without database is not overly difficult to accomplish. There are certainly exisiting solutions, just bad to google. Incidentally that are a multitude of scripts which manage .htpasswd files, which might be sufficient in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other solutions like that, but I can't [find](http://www.google.com/search?q=.htpasswd+php+user+management+script) nicer links right now:

- http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Authentication/AuthMan-Free-42216.html
- http://www.phpkode.com./scripts/item/passwdauth/
- http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/htaccess-manager-lite/
- http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/needlock-access-management-system/
- http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/dirlock/  (Ooops. Too many hotscripts links. So just saying: not affiliated with that. :] And certainly not endorsing it!)

Anyway. These scripts store usernames and passwords into a `.htpasswd` file. This can be used independently from the PHP script. `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` is common authentication scheme for Apache webservers. See this tutorial: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml or the Apache manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

You could use the class itself for authentication, but it doesn't look very current. The login management tool might be useful to you. (But again: there are probably easier ones to find.)

Answer (score 6):

Depends on your webserver. Assuming apache, [`htpasswd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html) for basic auth could be all you need.

[Authentication, Authorization and Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html) gives the information you need to get started.

Comment: Yea i am running apache, could you tell me how to save usernames and passwords to protect a web page with multiple usernames and passwords??

Comment: click on the links and read. use your favorite search engine after that, there are loads of examples/tutorials out there (and on this site).

Comment: i think htpassword protect entire web pages. Is there any way to protect custom pages with multiple un & pw??

Comment: please read the second link posted. It tells you exactly how you can use multiple users & passwords. follow the other links and search google.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using localhost, then wouldn't everyone have access to the filesystem?

I think the simplest solution is [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) though.

Comment: could you tell me how to save usernames and passwords to protect a web page??

Comment: [Authentication, Authorization and Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at www.mykonosphotographs.com/musas/

I'm still in the process of writing a download page, but I can email you the script if you're interested. Use the contact from on the site.

It's a major modification to a single-password system written by someone else, and I've added lots of extra functionality which you can use or not, as you like.

Currently free. It won't be as soon as I've got the downloads page sorted! ;-)

Edit - too late! The downloads page is now sorted.

New URL - http://www.myksoftware.com

Answer (score 0):

nope.

unless you want to save all information to files (like csvs)

but this could be a security threat if anyone got access to the files (which is easier than gaining access to a database)

[php doc for reading csv file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: i need a simple solution like csv.. Dont worry about security :)

Comment: @blasteralfred so that is ur answer ^_^

Comment: @Neal, could you tell me how to save usernames and passwords to protect a web page with multiple usernames and passwords??

Comment: same way you would do with a database. read up on csv file reading with php. again, you have to protect the files somehow (encode them? idk)

Comment: "if anyone got access to the files (which is easier than gaining access to a database)" - I don't agree with that at all, the files would almost certainly contain the login details for the db (unless you are using SQL server and AD), so one pretty much gives the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide almost anything by various means.

For example, if your webspace provider permits it you can place files outside of your root directory. You can place files in a directory with some weird name like "jdf83usadj300p", with no link to them other than in php, which is parsed by serverside software without the clientside software ever seeing it. You can place passwords in a config file, if you call it something like "config.php" and make the first line:-

; <? php die(); ?>

Only an idiot would use the various javaScript "protection" methods out there like making the password the name of the next file. .htaccess can be cumbersome and can put people off. Far better make it attractive using server-side software.

If passwords are likely to be attacked, ALWAYS encrypt them. NEVER pass passwords from one page to another by GET method unless already encrypted. POST is more secure. md5 encrypting for most purposes is good, with encryption in-built in PHP and many algorithms out there freely available for javaScript. SHA-256 is almost the best there is fo almost any purpose. I don't think the US DoD or the UK MOD would be satisfied with it, but your local sports club's website (or similar) isn't exactly going to be a high-profile target for hackers.

Incidentally, blasteralfred, I sent you an email update. Hope you got it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you could try usered php, it uses an sqlite database so is more or less plug and play, you just unzip it in your server and change permission of the data folder to CHMOD 777 to make it writable and you are good to go, i use it most of the time when i dont have access to mysql. its reliable, search for it on github. or you can create your own in PDO+sqlite then when you want to migrate to mysql or other server you just change one line on the connection script.